# meadows and fields, aren't $0^{-1}=0$ can be proven simply from the axioms of fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

[Recall field axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html)

In this article
http://www-compsci.swan.ac.uk/~csjvt/JVTPublications/RationalsAsADT.pdf

Page 4, we have the SIP
\begin{matrix}
\left(-x\right)^{-1}=-\left(x^{-1}\right) \\
\left(x\cdot y\right)^{-1}=x^{-1}\cdot y^{-1}\\
\left(x^{-1}\right)^{-1}=x \\
\end{matrix}

And then page 7 we are shown how this and the ring axioms lead to the conclusion $0^{-1}=0$

> Q1: But isn't the expressions in SIP also true (can be derived) for fields (at least for $x \neq 0$), and since the proof to show that $0^{-1}=0$ rely only on the SIP and ring axioms (CR in the article), shouldn't we are able to derive the same result from the field axioms, that is concluding that $0^{-1}=0$ even for fields by simply introducing a new element $0^{-1}$ and show via the workings shown in the article that this element must $=0$?

In a follow up paper of the subject where the authors introduce non involutive meadows
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2092v1.pdf

Page 6

It is said by putting x=0 in $$(x^{∽1})^{∽1} = x + (1 − x \cdot x^{∽1})$$
and 
$$x^{∽1} \cdot (x^{∽1})^{∽1} = 1$$

we can conclude

$$0^{∽1} \cdot (0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 1$$
$$(0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 1$$

Hence

$$0^{∽1} = 1$$

> Q2 But how does $$(0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 0 + (1 − 0 \cdot 0^{∽1})$$
>   gives $$(0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 1$$?

**Attempted self workings**

Start with axiom

$$(x^{∽1})^{∽1} = x + (1 − x \cdot x^{∽1})$$

Put x=0 gives

$$(0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 0 + (1 − 0 \cdot 0^{∽1})$$

Using the additive identity property $x+0=x$

$$(0^{∽1})^{∽1} = 1 − 0 \cdot 0^{∽1}$$

But what implies

$$0 \cdot 0^{∽1}=0$$

Is it because of the derived property of rings that $x \cdot 0 = 0$ for any x in the ring, and that $0^{\sim 1}$ is just one of the elements in the ring thus it has to obey this property also?

Comment: For example, look at the fields of real/rational numbers; $0$ has no inverse here under standard multiplication.

Comment: @Rod - in a ring not every nonzero element needs to have a multiplicative inverse: consider the ring of integers

Comment: A multiplicative inverse is such that multiplying something by its multiplicative inverse gives the multiplicative identity.   

If you define $0^{-1}:=0$ then $0 \cdot 0^{-1}=0\not = 1$ and so $0^{-1}$ is not the multiplicative inverse of $0$. So $x^{-1}$ would no longer have the meaning it has in the field axioms.

Comment: On your Q2, $0\cdot x=0$ is a property of a ring, making $0 + (1 − 0 \cdot 0^{∽1}) = 0+ (1 − 0 ) =1$

Comment: To try to ward off any more comments along the lines of "impossible for $0$ to have a multiplicative inverse," we should really note that the papers in question do not assume that $xx^{-1}=1$ is satisfied at all. They *look* like multiplicative inverses, but that is not what is axiomatically described in the paper.

Comment: The papers also seem to notational catastrophes of the most fearsome kind :) At least, I found the choices of axiom group labels very unintuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But isn't the expressions in SIP also true (can be derived) for fields (at least for $x≠0$)...

Yes, and indeed on page 4 the authors even say so: "Guarded versions of SIP - such as $x \neq 0 \implies (x^{−1})^{−1} = x^{-1}$ can be proved from Gil and
Sep." They mention there also that the group CR, Gil and Sep form the ordinary field axioms.

> since the proof to show that $0^{−1}=0$ rely only on the SIP and ring axioms...

Yes, this shows that $0^{-1}=0$ in any commutative ring. The problem is that $0^{-1}$ is *not* a multiplicative inverse for $0$, as the notation suggests. It's simply another symbol for $0$, one which lacks the defining property that multiplicative inverses have.

> Is it because of the derived property of rings that $x⋅0=0$ for any $x$ in the ring...?

Yes, all the axiom groups I saw there appeared to include the axiom group CR, and that equation is true for any element $x$ in a commutative ring.